# How to empty a collection, rebuild index, then fill the collection again?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

The MongoDB API in Azure (Cosmos DB) [does not support creating/rebuilding/dropping unique indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-indexing#migrating-collections-with-indexes) on collections that contain documents. This is a real problem when doing scripted schema changes to documents in collections if the changes affect the indexes. In those cases I would like to drop the conflicting index prior to doing the changes and then create or rebuild the indexes afterwards. An example would be:

```
db.collection('example').dropIndexes(() => {
  db.collection('example').find().toArray(function (err, docs) {

    // Do changes to docs here, create new index etc.

  }
}
```

Since this is not possible in Azure (`dropIndexes()` will fail), what could be a possible workaround? Can I somehow keep the documents in memory while deleting them, and then alter indexes, and re-inserting them again afterwards? Or move them to another, temporary collection, then move them back when done? If so, would I keep the `_id`s?

Comment: FYI. No such thing as "MongoDB in Azure via CosmosDB". It's **CosmosDB** and "CosmosDB only". It's purportedly *supposed to* support accepting instructions via the MongoDB wire protocol. But it's **not MongoDB** in any way, and therefore does not act **exactly** like MongoDB.

Comment: Now that's out of the way, [the documentation disagrees with you](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-indexing). Notably you are not checking the result or error in your callback function. Instead `dropIndexes((err,result) => ...` and look at what those actually say. Then include that in your question.

Comment: @NeilLunn, I see wasn't fully aware of how Cosmos worked. I've edited the question. I've also clarified that I'm talking about unique indexes, and added a link to the part of the documentation that describes that it's not possible. My code sample was just a sample, and I've seen the error message multiple times. I don't have the specific message for dropping right now, but upon creating it says "Code 13 Unique Index can be modified only if collection is empty". Dropping has a similar error. My question is how I can work around the fact that CosmosDB Mongo API doesn't allow this.

Comment: generally, this type of scenario I used to transfer my collection data into a new collection using "Cosmos Data Migration Tool" then drop collection then re-create collection with the same name and transfer data back to the original collection. I didn't try this with Mongo API but I did with SQL API.

Comment: The documentation link included in the question ( as well as being referenced in the link given earlier ) does generally suggest that you essentially drop the existing collections after making a copy of the data and then issuing new "create collection" and "create index" commands when unique indexes are involved. All of that should indeed be supported by the MongoDB API layer as long as the collections are newly created and empty. That said, I generally agree with the sentiment that there is a CosmosDB **native** API, and a lot of your "setup" should be using that, **if** you use CosmosDB.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, so it seems like the best solution is to move the documents, recreate the collection and then re-enter the documents. @NeilLunn regarding *should be using the native CosmosDB API* - perhaps in a perfect world, but the application is run on native MongoDB in dev environments and I just recently started seeing these weird differences between CosmosDB with Mongo API and true MongoDB that I didn't really know about beforehand. Leaving CosmosDB is imho a better option and something I will strive for..